# What's the point of naming forms?

Tags: html, forms

What's point of the `name=""` html attribute in `<form>` tags? [Here](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_form_name.asp) it just says that:

> The name attribute specifies the name of a form. The name attribute is
>   used to reference elements in a JavaScript.

Why can't we use the `id` or `class` attribute to reference elements with Javascript?

What was the `name` tag intended for? Has it any real importance today?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `<form>` name attribite pre-dates using IDs in JavaScript, therefore it is there to backwards compatibility. It also forms a collection `document.forms` which can be handy when parsing a page.

Answer (score 2):

You can access form using name reference in javascript.
Before jquery was invented, javascript used to access DOM elements using name, as well as Ids. 
You can refer [this](http://www.javascript-coder.com/javascript-form/javascript-get-all-form-objects.phtml) for further clarifications.

And for other HTML elements, element name is used at server end, to retrieve POST parameters.

```
$test = $_POST['name'];
```

Answer (score 0):

W3C says same here http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#h-17.3 `name` attribute is just for scripting. Yes, one can use `id` attribute for that and id's is commonly used with jQuery or like.

However, there is some things, that corresponds to what w3c states, you can do with name. One example is javascript `document.forms['formname']` to access form element. Described here http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-HTML/html.html#ID-40002357